# How to get sticker name?

Tags: api, steam, steam-web-api

On this page I can get wear value:

> http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetPlayerItems/v0001/

Wear: 0.52518285642000003

```
"attributes": [
        {
            "defindex": 114,
            "value": 1054449450,
            "float_value": 0.52518285642000003
        },
        ...]
```

`"defindex": 114 == "name": "sticker slot 0 wear"` (GetSchema)

I can get sticker wear on this page (GetPlayerItems), but how to get the name of a sticker? Or some unique number of thing?

Comment: Following that link (after appending `?key={my key}&format=json` to it) results in a "Bad Request" error page for me...

Comment: @Rhymoid this api is unstable. You need some time to refresh to get the result...

Comment: @Rhymoid and your link should look like this : `http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetPlayerItems/v1/?key={API_KEY}&format=json&steamid={STEAM_ID}`